# How to protect Perl program from abort() call in a module?

Tags: perl, module, ipc

Consider this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
require 5.006_001;
use Graphics::Magick;

# this sets a handler for ABRT
use sigtrap qw( die any );

sub try { my ($err) = @_; die("$err\n") if $err; }

my $image = Graphics::Magick->new;

sub process {
    my ($file) = @_;

    my $result = eval {
        kill 'ABRT',$$ if $file eq "magic";
        try $image->Read($file);
    };

    if (defined $result) { print "Yay :)\n"; }
    else { warn($@); }
}

process "good.gif";  # works
process "MINN.XK4";  # needs font that doesn't exist
process "magic";     # trigger abort manually
process "foo";       # file doesn't exist
```

I had assumed that this would protect the main program from problems in the module, and it mostly does. However, I recently encountered a situation where some implementations of the module trigger an assertion failure.

With most versions of the module, I see something like:

```
Yay :)
Exception 405: Unable to read font (/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/n021003l.pfb)
Caught a SIGABRT at ./example line 18.
Exception 430: Unable to open file (foo)
```

However, with at least one version, this result is possible:

```
Yay :)
perl: magick/draw.c:1777: DrawSetFont: Assertion `font_name != (const char *) NULL' failed.
Aborted
```

The output above is showing that this version of the module is calling assert(3) at [line 1777 of the module](https://sourceforge.net/p/graphicsmagick/code/ci/default/tree/magick/draw.c) (most versions fail gracefully as in the first output). However the ABRT is not being caught by my signal handlers (set by `sigtrap`), even though it **is** caught when I explicitly send that signal (`kill` above) in the Perl code.

How should I rewrite to better insulate the main program against these signals from the module?

---

It seems that for many years I have misunderstood what the `eval` is good for and, apparently, I don't really understand signal handling. Why is an ABORT/IOT triggered by an assert() call in the module `.so` different from triggering one as I do above?

My manpage for abort(3) says:

> The abort() function first unblocks the SIGABRT signal, and then raises that signal for the calling process (as though  raise(3)  was  called). This  results  in  the  abnormal  termination of the process unless the SIGABRT signal is caught and the signal handler does  not  return  (see longjmp(3)).

So perhaps there is a Perl way to "not return"? `perldoc perlvar` tells me:

> The routine indicated by `$SIG{__DIE__}` is called when a fatal exception is about to be thrown. The error message is passed as the first argument. When a "`__DIE__`" hook routine returns, the exception processing continues as it would have in the absence of the hook, unless the hook routine itself exits via a "`goto &sub`", a loop exit, or a "`die()`". The "`__DIE__`" handler is explicitly disabled during the call, so that you can die from a "`__DIE__`" handler. Similarly for "`__WARN__`".

but I'm not sure how to use this information.

Comment: Use sigaction to tell the syscalls to auto restart if they can?

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, that went over my head. Does this provide a mechanism for the Perl program to cancel/ignore the assert(3)+abort(3) invoked by the module?

Comment: The assert is probably failing because a syscall failed. A signal coming in during a syscall may cause it to fail with EINTR

Comment: Failing to proof it, consider splitting off the "risky" processing in a separate executable, invoked by the main program?  Then the main code survives and can handle the failure as suitable.

Comment: @zdim Yes, that's certainly an option

Comment: running strace, the Perl `kill` that gets caught and handled invokes kill(2); the GM `assert()` invokes tgkill(2)